# Not able to see the jquery UI date time picker in textbox in a view

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to put the jquery datetime picker in textbox by using the following link [Jquery UI Date time Picker](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2011/01/25/asp-net-mvc-3-integrating-with-**the-jquery-ui-date-picker-and-adding-a-jquery-validate-date-range-validator.aspx)

When I click on the date textbox i am not able to see the date time picker in a view
and for that purpose I have done like this..
this is my view

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/RangeDateValidator.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquerydatetimepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
         $('.date').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });
       // $('.date').datetimepicker();
    });
</script>
@model MvcSampleApplication.Models.DateEditModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "EditDateTimePick";
    //Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>EditDateTimePick</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
    @Html.EditorFor(s=>s.DtpJqry)
    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

and this is my controller part

```
public class DateTimePickersController : Controller
{       
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("EditDateTimePick");
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit()
    {
        DateEditModel model = new DateEditModel();
        {
            var datetimechange = new DatePickerJquery { Name = "Raj", date = new DateTime(2010, 12, 15) };           
        };
        return View(model);
    }
    public ActionResult Edit(DatePickerJquery dtpjquery)
    {
        string message = null;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            message = "Saved" + DateTime.Now;            
        }
        DateEditModel models = new DateEditModel { 
              DtpJqry = dtpjquery,
              Message = message                        
        };
        return View(models);
    }
}
```

and this is another view

```
@model DateTime
@Html.TextBox("", Model.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), new { @class = "date" })
```

**Modified View:**

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/RangeDateValidator.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
         $('.date').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });
       // $('.date').datetimepicker();
    });
</script>
@model MvcSampleApplication.Models.DateEditModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "EditDateTimePick";
    //Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>EditDateTimePick</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
    @Html.EditorFor(s=>s.DtpJqry)
    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

would any one pls suggest any ideas on how its not showing the datetimepicker that would be very grateful for me
Many thanks in advance....

Comment: What error did you get in Console ?

Comment: I am not getting any error , but I am able to see the textbox in view but when i click in textbox , it should show datetime picker but its ot ...

Answer (score 1):

Your almost there. you have the date time picker looking at all tags with the class `date` you just need to add that class to your field.

```
<h2>EditDateTimePick</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
    @Html.EditorFor(s=>s.DtpJqry, new { Class="date" })
    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

**update**

Take out the min from your script references so you are only referencing the jQuery UI once:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/RangeDateValidator.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquerydatetimepicker.js"></script>
```

**Update 2**

Template partial views need to exist in specific folder names and the name of the partial view file should be the name of the type.

`EditorTemplates` - for editors or

`DisplayTemplates` - for display

```
- Shared
    -EditorTemplates
        DateTime.cshtml
```

This will allow for the follwing syntax to work:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyDateTimeProperty)
```

Comment: hmm sorry for that I forgot add partial view...I have added partial view pls look at my edit and pls suggest any ideas

Comment: Your parital view is loosing the name of the property you are exposing, and so will not post back correctly. Also just noticed you are referencing the ui script twice, take out the .min and replace it back when you go into production.

Comment: how can I add that property ...would you pls tell I am new to MVC

Comment: In order for your partial view to work, it must be in a sub view directory called `EditorTemplates` and the name must be `DateTime.ascx`

Comment: I have changed view name (DateTime.cshtml) to DateTime.ascx in EditorTemplates subview folder, still not able to see the datetime picker in date textbox i am using visual studio 2012...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34274/discussion-between-jay-and-pratap-k)

Answer (score 0):

$('#txtDtpJqry').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });

Instead of EditorFor try TextboxFor by declaring the id or class for that textbox. 
@Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.DtpJqry, new { id = "txtDtpJqry" })

its works fine.

Comment: I am not able to get the results even i changed this line

Comment: I am getting this error    Unhandled exception at line 23, column 10 in http://localhost:portnumber/DateTimePickers

0x800a01b6 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method      at this line   :  @Html.TextBoxFor(s => s.DtpJqry, new { id = "txtDtpJqry" });

Comment: can you follow this link http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/0ab88e11-5a8b-4753-85ce-06b3dfa3954b/0x800a01b6-microsoft-jscript-runtime-error-object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method   There is no issue on code. Instead you have issue on Jquery plugins.

Comment: Suggestion: you have @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") then why did you integrate the below scripts into that page. Remove these below script, <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquerydatetimepicker.js"></script> these plugins in this page. Integrate above scripts in Bundle.cs file.